# Looking for Kafka docker image for supporting arm64

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, arm64

Recently I am moving to MacBook with Apple M1 chip, my previous Kafka docker image is obsidiandynamics/kafka, but offically it doesn't support arm64 so far.

My question is,
(1) is it possible to let obsidiandynamics/kafka support arm64?

(2) are there any alternative Kafka images to support arm64? Ideally it is compatible to obsidiandynamics/kafka.

Thanks your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It doesn't look like [obsidiandynamics/kafka](https://hub.docker.com/r/obsidiandynamics/kafka) has been maintained for years, so it seems unlikely that they'll be adding an arm64 version of the image.
2. I've recently used the [wurstmeister/kafka](https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/kafka) image in a [sample project](https://github.com/architect-community/node-kafka) and it ran as expected on a new MacBook with the M1 chip, so that could be a good alternative.

Comment: Just want to add an update that wurstmeister no longer appears to be maintained. Try bitnami for all your kafka needs. They appear to maintain many arm64 images for all kinds of things. Zookeeper, kafka, schema-registry, postgresql, etc...

https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kafka